# Как создать N файлов с названиями вида N.txt?

Tags: c, файлы

Как можно создать N файлов с названиями вида `N.txt`? Предполагается, что число N вводит пользователь.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "пронумерованными" файлами?

Comment: @Harry.Извините,забыл написать.Пронумерованы названия файлов.Например:1.txt,2.txt и т.д.

Comment: Имея имя - вы можете "создать файл" (сделать то, что вы под этим подразумеваете)? Тогда просто в цикле создаете соответствующие имена, и из них - файлы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала сформируем имя файла с помощью функции [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
char file_name[FILENAME_MAX];
snprintf(file_name, sizeof file_name, "%u.txt", file_number);
```

Теперь, чтобы создать файл с заданным именем воспользуемся функцией [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen):

```
FILE *f;

if ((f = fopen(file_name, "w+")))
    fclose(f);
```

Важно решить, что делаеть, если файл уже существует. В текущем варианте, если файл с данным именем уже существует, то его содержимое будет уничтожено, за что отвечает флаг `w+`<sup>1</sup>.

Если вы не хотите уничтожать содержимое в случае, если файл уже существует, можете воспользоваться флагом `a`.

---

<sup>1. В C11 появилась возможность добавить флаг `x` к флагам `w` и `w+`, что вызовет ошибку при создании файла, если он уже существует, вместо уничтожения его содержимого.</sup>

Comment: А зачем флаг `w+`? Он же стирает данные в файле, если файл уже существует. Замените его на `ｗ`.

Comment: @ヒミコ, я упомянул это поведение в вопросе. Автор не уточнял, что нужно делать, если файл уже существует. Автор может спокойно заменить `w+` на какой-нибудь другой режим.

Comment: @eanmos спасибо большое за помощь :3

Comment: @eanmos а чем заполнить строку file_name?Когда я задаю ее длину,но не указываю элементы файлы не создаются

Comment: @ТельманБабаев, вам нужно присвоить переменной `file_number` какое-нибудь значение, например, 23. Тогда создаться файл `23.txt`. Если менять значение `file_number` в цикле, можно будет создать файлы `1.txt`, `2.txt`, ...

Comment: @ТельманБабаев, если все еще есть какие-нибудь трудности, то вот [полный пример](https://ideone.com/6G1w2T).

Comment: @eanmos благодарю